# How to find the profit earned from getting right a set of logic statements?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, propositional-calculus

The problem is as follows:

Diana offers her sister Maria $3$ bitcoins for each true statement and $4$ bitcoins for each false that she finds correctly in the statements shown, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the universal set for the variables $x$ and $y$.

I. $\forall y; \forall x: x^2+y^2>0$

II. $\exists x; \exists y: x+y<2xy$

III. $\forall x; \exists y: x+y=0$

How many bitcoins did Maria receive, after answering all of them correctly?

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{11 bitcoins}\\
2.&\textrm{12 bitcoins}\\
3.&\textrm{10 bitcoins}\\
4.&\textrm{9 bitcoins}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly this problem should be approached?. I'm stuck at the part where it comes the inequalities, from then on I don't know what to do. Can someone help me?.

The thing which I'm getting is that the set from where $x$ and $y$ belong to is $\mathbb{Z}$ hence we're talking about integers but I don't know how to use this information to further solve this problem. Can someone help me from this part in **the most detailed way as possible and step by step?.**

Comment: Can you read the statements in English?  For the first, for all integer $x,y$ we have $x^2+y^2 \gt 0$.  Is that true?

Comment: No, it is not true.  You can have $x=0, y=0$

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry about that, I just figured that, hence deleted the previous comment. Okay, then what?. Let's see, the second is a little bit complicated because if you consider a positive and negative, assuming $x=0$ and $y=0$ then it is false. Am I right with this?, Then in the third you could choose your given values and this may yield true. But this is the part where I'm stuck. In this scenario would meant $8+3=11$ hence $11$ bitcoins. But what about the other options?. Don't they count or what?.

Comment: You need to understand the quantifiers.  $\forall$ means for all and $\exists$ means there exists.  For 2, if you can find one example you are done because it shows there exists and $x$ and $y$ that make the sentence true.  As I said before, read the sentence aloud in English and think about it.  The point of the exercise is to understand the quantifiers.

Comment: @RossMillikan Okay I just did that, now I'm getting the idea of understanding the quantifiers in the problem. When you get two times for all, then this means if one doesn't comply with the statement, then it is false, right?. in the second as you indicated is true as there exist a value which may verify the statement and the third is also true because there exist an integer which would make the statement true. Hence Maria would earn $6+4=10$ bitcoins?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: How does someone with 3k reputation here ask a question like this? Is my question too impolite to be asked? OP describes himself as a scientist.

Comment: @user4894 it’s not clear why a chemist should be adept with quantifiers...

Comment: @KevinArlin I can see that. I was just expecting, "We don't do homework here," or "What have you tried?" Especially because OP already got a lot of good advice when he posted the same question on another math forum a couple of days ago. I see a striking lack of effort here (and on the other forum) that is never encouraged on this site as it has been for this particular question. I admit I'm puzzled, but clearly it's just me. OP's question history shows study of number theory. There's something off about this and that's all I can say. OP already got plenty of help on the other forum 2 days ago.

Comment: @user4894 You seem to be focusing considerable energy on the journeys of this question across the Net...I think you should go focus on something else. If people choose to vote to close the question, it will be closed. This isn’t really a very big deal.

Comment: @KevinArlin Considerable energy? How so? Because I happened to see the exact same question *answered in considerable detail* on a popular math site? My puzzlement is that I've often -- very often -- seen similar questions get absolutely hammered on SE with "What have you done so far?" and "This is not a venue for homework questions." Yet that didn't happen here. I'm truly puzzled. I expressed my puzzlement.

Answer (score 1):

To start, I found it helpful to write the terminology out in more details:

1. When dealing with ∀ (for all), you need only one case where it is false, since that means not all integers work
2. When dealing with ∃ (there exists), you only need one case where it is *true*, since that means there exists at least one valid answer
3. When combination, you are back to only needing one case where it is false but it is a bit simpler because it must be a case where the ∀ variable is the one that makes the statement impossible to resolve.

Since you mentioned you had an issue with the inequalities, let's look at techniques for those. I've used a lot of spoiler tags since it can be helpful to try to guess yourself before seeing the next conclusion.

As general tool, it helps to list out the properties of integers, such as (not an exhaustive list):

- Any positive integer is greater than any negative integer
- A positive times a negative is negative; a positive times a positive (including squaring) is a positive; a negative times a negative (including squaring) is positive;
- Multiplying by zero gives you zero
- All positive integers have one equivalent negative integer such that x + y = 0
- Any integer divided by or multiplied by 1 remains the same ($1x=x$,$y/1=y$)

For ∀ and an inequality, I sometimes flip the inequality and try to prove that there exists ∃ a case for which it is true since I find ∃ simpler to deal with. In this case, that means evaluating

> $∃y;∃x:x^2+y^2≤0$

Then breaking that into two parts:

> The inequality portion, $x^2 + y^2 < 0$, is always false, because squaring any non-zero integer, positive or negative, will  give you a positive number.

> However, the equality case can be resolved to a true statement, since $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ is true if $x,y=0$.

Because there exists (∃) a case for which $x^2 + y^2 ≤ 0$, it *cannot* be true that for all (∀) $x,y$ the condition $x^2 + y^2 > 0$ is satisfied.

For the second inequality $∃x;∃y:x+y<2xy$, I would go back to the properties of integers. In this case,

> A positive integer is always greater than a negative integer, multiplying two negative integers will always yield a positive, and adding two negative integers will results in a negative integer.

Therefore,

> Taking all those into account, if x,y are *any* two negative integers, 2xy will be positive and x+y will be negative, and thus ∃ two integers such that $x+y<2xy$

Answer (score 0):

Try some numbers:

The first is False since $0^2+0^2=0$.

For the second one, let $x$ and $y$ takes some values. For example, you can set $x$ to be $0$ and determine if you can find your $y$.

Comment: Assuming that you stick with zero for both x and y for all the three statements this would make in the end Maria got 11 bitcoins. But I don't know the intended meaning in this question. I mean **why are you looking at a case which renders the first statement false?** Can you explain this part? The problem indicates she answers all correctly. But what's that meaning?. Wouldn't it mean that all are set true?. This part is confusing.

Comment: You should examine each sentence and check if each statement is true. I have proven that $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, x^2+y^2 >0$ is a false statement. check for the second and the third as well. hmmm.... "the problem indicates that she answers all correctly?" you mean the book told you so?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused about the quantifiers as indicated in the comments from above. The thing is the number of bitcoins earned is 10. Given the second and third statements are true and the first is false. Am I right with this?

Comment: yes, that is right. (False, True, True)

Comment: No the book did not told me that. I mean the statement in the problem indicates that Maria does answer correctly all the statements but this does not imply that such statements are true or false. It indicates that Maria did the right interpretation of these. Am I right here?

Comment: Maria answered the question correctly. (False, True, True) , so she gets $4+3+3$ bitcoins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117639/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-chris-steinbeck-bell).